# Latest wordpress posts on static website - menu not working anymore

Tags: wordpress, static, web, embed, posts

Until now I had the latest Wordpress posts on my static website. All worked fine.
For some reason now the menu isn't working anymore.
I didn't change the code, so it must be something at the Wordpress end. Maybe the latest update of my theme, I don't know.
The static page and menu works fine without the Wordpress code, so it must be something in that code.
I hope somebody can shed some light on this.
This is the code on the static page:

```html
<?php
require('./blog/wp-blog-header.php');
?>

<?php
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => 3, 'post_status'=>"publish",'post_type'=>"post",'orderby'=>"post_date");
    $postslist = get_posts( $args );
    foreach ($postslist as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
       <div class="events">
             <p><strong><?php the_date(); ?></strong></p>
           <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
           <?php the_content(); ?>
           <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'full'); ?>
      </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

And this is the static page: http://www.tina-turner.nl/news.php

Johanna

Comment: That code looks fine.  You've got some errors in the javascript console, the first of which is `Uncaught ReferenceError: wpa2a is not defined`, and the second of which seems to be calling a missing jQuery function called `yoxview`.  Have you disabled any plugins?

Comment: [This page](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/referenceerror-wpa2a-is-not-defined) seems to imply the first error relates to a plugin called "Add to Any" - is it enabled and up to date?

Comment: The plugin "Add to any" is enabled and up to date.

Answer (score 0):

I played with the code and found out, that this part is messing with the menu:
'orderby'=>"post_date"
When I use this code:

```html
<?php
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 3, 'order'=> 'DESC', 'orderby' => 'title' );
$postslist = get_posts( $args );
foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post); ?> 
    <div class="events">
        <?php the_date(); ?>
        <br />
        <?php the_title(); ?>   
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

the menu works. The only thing is, that the page doesn't display the latest 3 posts.
What can I change in the code to do that?
Here is my testpage: http://www.tina-turner.nl/news2.php

Johanna